# Vue - Nuxt - How to call a middleware on a layout?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, frontend, nuxt.js

I've created a middleware for authentication on my nuxt application, and I want to call it inside a layout.
Problem is, I'm calling it like this:

```
export default {
  
  middleware: 'auth',
```

and it is returning me the following warning:

```
callback-based asyncData, fetch or middleware calls are deprecated. Please switch to promises or async/await syntax
```

I'm new into the front-end world and I searched but couldn't find/understand how to implement this async/await syntax on my middleware call. Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess you have a file in the middleware folder with name auth.js . Inside there you export a function `export default async function(){ /** custom login return ''; **/}

Comment: aync/await not helping with this

Answer (score 2):

Faced a similar problem. I also use `middleware: ['lang']`, I got such an error and for a long time could not understand why this happened, if I did not change anything in the code. It turned out that in `lang.js` I mistakenly receive the second argument `req`

```
export default async function ({ isHMR, app, store }, req) {
}
```

Only a function `servermiddleware` can take multiple arguments

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
```